# asp.net dynamically add usercontrols and position them

Tags: c#, asp.net

My issue is that I have a designer that will create a custom aspx page bu without any .net controls.  I need a way of adding the controls dynamically.  So far the only types of controls will be textboxes and a button, but there are 30 variations of what the textboxes can be (name, phone #, email, etc).  Also the textboxes may or may not need to be required.  Once the textboxes are added the form will be submitted to a db.

My first thought was to have the designer place something like [name] and then replace that with a user control that has a name textbox and a required field validator.  In order to determine if the validator should be enabled I was thinking that the place holder could look like this, [name;val] or [name;noval].  I could either do replace the place holders in code dynamically or set up a tool that the user pastes their html into a textbox and clicks a button which then spits out the necessary code to create the aspx page.

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this but its a fairly unique problem so I haven't been able to find any alternatives.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Kirk

Comment: Why can't the designer use the ASP.NET controls directly? Markup was separated from code also for supporting these activities.

Comment: Your designer is doing you a disservice. It would be easier for him to design it, you to add the controls in and then for him to style it. That's ridiculous that he can't use .NET controls.

Comment: I was asked to do this in order to crank out forms quickly.  I'm not sure why the designer can't place the controls himself to be honest

Answer (score 0):

IF your designer gives you html pages, just create a new website. copy and pages all the HTML pages with the Image folders and everything to your project. then for every HTML page create an aspx page, (with the same name) copy and pages the html's tags which are between  to the aspx page's  and for the body copy and paste HTML page's tags which are between  into the  of the aspx page. 
Now you have your aspx page, exactly the same as html page.

Comment: The issue with this is that I'm basically not going to be involved with the forms as they're created.  The purpose of this is to allow the designer and the department he's in to be able to create these forms independently

Comment: I had the same problem when working with designers in separate departments. I solved my problem by installing VS 2010 Express on the designers' machines and thought them how to do everything in VS designer. It then saved my a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an attempt to over-engineer a solution to what *should* be a non-issue.

As @Alessandro mentioned in a comment above, why can't the designer provide you with pages that have the control markup?  As it stands right now, the designer isn't providing you with "a custom aspx" so much as "a custom html page."  If the designer is promising ASPX but delivering only HTML, that's a misinterpretation somewhere in the business requirements.

However, even if the designer is rightfully providing only HTML, there shouldn't be a problem with that.  At worst, you can set each element you need on the server to `runat="server"` to access them on the server-side.  Or, probably better, would be to simply replace them with the ASPX control markup for the relevant controls.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple parser that will recognize the [...] tags and replace them with corresponding controls. Its pretty easy to do and i've often done this... the tag i use is usually $$(..); though, but that doesn't matter as long as your parser knows your tags.

Such a parser will consist of a simple state-machine that can be in two states; text-mode or tag-mode. Loop through the whole page-text, char for char. As long as you're in text-mode you keep appending each char into a temporary buffer. As soon as you get into tag-mode you create a LiteralControl with the content of the temporary buffer and add it to the bottom of your Control-tree, and emtpy the buffer.

Now, you still keep adding each char into the buffer, but when you hit text-mode again, you analyze the content of the buffer and create the correct control  - could be a simple switch case statement. Add the control to the bottom of your control tree and keep looping through the rest of the chars unto you read the end and keep switching back and forth between text-mode and tag-mode adding LiteralControls and concrete controls.

Simple example of such a parser... written in notepad in 4 minutes, but you should get the idea.

```
foreach (var c in text)
{
   buffer.Append(c);

   if (c== '[' && mode == Text) 
   { 
      mode = Tag;

      Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(buffer));
      buffer.Clear();
   }

   if (c == ']' && mode == Tag) 
   {   
      mode = Text;

      switch (buffer)
      {
         case "[name]": Controls.Add(new NameControl());
         ... the rest of possible tags
      }

      buffer.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing something along these lines.  I'm just curious  to see if there was a better way of doing this that I wasn't thinking of. Thanks

Comment: you could do some Regular Expression matching, and extract the text using start and end indexes of the matches but a simple parser like this will always be faster.